# Could the Roman Empire have survived if it existed alongside an advanced feudal state?

Tags: society, civilization

There are two ways of looking at history of humankind: In one, most of the changes taken through the history are from less advanced to more advanced societies. In another, there are many random effects and quite often, you take steps back. If you strongly believe in progress, then feudalism was probably superior to the societies of the ancient Egypt, the ancient Greece or the Roman Empire.

My question is: *If you put the Roman Empire from year ~100 AD alongside with some advanced early feudal state (e.g. the Holy Roman Empire from year 1100 AD), which one would prevail?*

I am not interested in any specific scenario (where you put which empire, if they will make war, etc.) Rather I am interested in whether the society of the Roman Empire and other advanced civilizations before the middle ages would be able to cope with the (theoretically more advanced) feudal society, or if it would fall apart.

Comment: Superior on what measure?

Comment: Military, organisation and ability to remain unchanged by the cultural influence of the other society.

Comment: It the question more appropriate on http://history.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I am not sure - the question is rather speculative for the history stackexchange and it definitely touches the worlbuilding topic. (If you are, for example, hesitating if there should be coexistence of feudal and slavetrading societies in your world.)

Comment: Alternate history is on topic, though "prevail" could do with a little more focusing. You need to include criteria for success. Prevail is broad. Voting to leave open for now (though that should be addressed in the question). You also appear to *ask your question* and then ask if it would fall apart. Focus on one or the other :P

Comment: As Tim said, it's not clear what you mean by superior. They are different but I don't think one is better than the other. You do know that the Eastern Roman Empire survived the fall of Rome and was quite powerful during the middle ages, especially in the first half. In 1452, Constantinople was still one of the greatest cities in the world, really rich.So, I would like if you could give some arguments that makes you think one is superior to the other.

Comment: That would help to narrow the question.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to extend the question tomorrow and put some arguments for and against.

Comment: Rome actually did live near an advanced Feudal state. Parthia and Persia were exactly that.

Comment: If this were reworded a bit, it could be a good question. If you had a world where a nation very like Imperial Rome happened to be next to nations very like medieval European nations, would Rome be able to compete and survive with these later nations nearby? The answer is very much YES, if you mean a healthy Rome (e.g. under Augustus). I would say that the medieval nations would be very much in danger of conquest by Rome. Rome was more advanced, organized, expansionist and ruthless than medieval European nations in many ways.

Comment: If Rome were next to a "superior" feudal society X, X would either be far larger and more stable than any feudal state that existed in real life (or that history suggests *could* exist: feudalism is not stable), or Rome would simply buy up/reverse engineer X's technology and then overtake them.

Answer (score 12):

The [Eastern Roman Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_Empire) survived until 1453, and for a long time it "coped" fairly well in its interactions with Western feudal states.

More generally, I don't think any serious historian believes in a monotonic "upward march of progress". The Roman Empire at its height was better at some things and worse at others, compared with its successors 1000 years later. In particular, Roman bureaucracy, logistics, and civil engineering were not equalled in Western Europe until 1500 CE or later.

There is no reason to suppose Rome would "collapse" if the tribes inhabiting Germany in 100 AD were suddenly replaced by the Holy Roman Empire. The Romans are hardly going to say, "In Jupiter's name, these people have slightly better metallurgy than us, our society is at an end!" Instead they would probably learn to coexist, as they did with other neighbouring empires such as Persia.

For a real social "collapse" to take place, the technology gap needs to be much bigger -- think of Spain encountering the Aztecs and Incas. (Even then, the decline of native American empires had as much to do with European diseases as military conquest -- see [Guns, Germs and Steel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guns,_Germs,_and_Steel) by Jared Diamond for an interesting discussion.)

Comment: I do not know that much about history, but didn't the Eastern Roman Empire change into the feudal society before that?

Comment: It's a bit complicated -- there were some feudal aspects to the Byzantine Empire, but also continuity with the centralized Roman bureaucracy of the past. And it depends what era you're talking about, it changed quite a lot during the 1000 or so years it existed.

Answer (score 2):

That´s hard to answer... the Roman Empire was/is highly adaptive, and it still exists in the form of the Roman Catholic Church. Remember that Rome was first a kingdom, then a republic, and after that an empire. If during the imperial times, they collected taxes from provinces providing the bureaucracy and military protection necessary to commerce, and a Roman lifestyle, after the fall, Rome became the religious center of Europe. The Vatican remained as powerful as the old empire, dictating the policies and taxing eventually more territories (such as Vikings), without the burden of maintaining legions. And the Pope also de-facto ruled Rome until napoleonic times...

The fall of the Empire was due to several factors, but one important factor was the barbarian tribes with agile horseback units using pillage tactics. The open roads of the old "globalized" empire were obsolete, the foot based legions were not as fast as the barbarians. When the last Emperor was replaced by barbarians, the church became an independent power. They ended up converting all barbarians, that gladly payed high taxes to be crowned by... Romans. But the true power remained at the hands of the **roman** pope (187 of 217 popes were italians in all history).

It is hard to compare Feudalism with the Classical age. As for the "Holy Roman Emperor", it was just an honorific title! In pure military sense, you should compare some specific leader, such as Charlemagne of the Carolingian Empire with a Roman Emperor, such as Augustus or Constantine. I don´t think that Rome would stand heavy armored horsemen and the weapon advancements of the Franks. By the other hand, the Vatican is in Rome, how would you deal with its absence in this historical "twilight zone" scenario? How powerful the Franks would be without the catholic church? Would the servants still serve their masters? or defect to Rome?

Comment: Interesting. Do you think a Roman army would have kept its tactics unchanged or do you think they would have adapted somehow due to later emerging cavalry and archery tactics?

Comment: All pope had knights.The best of then. And gold to pay mercenaries. The best technology was always adopted.There is a book named "Sapiens" that claims that an empire is a political power over a group of politically controlled nations. The military control is one way of control, the oldest, but not the only one. Religion was the feudal way of control. You can say that mass media is the way of control today. This book has some interesting ideas about the concept of empire, that is distinct of nation or people (folk). An empire respects local power and incorporates it into a bigger system.

Comment: When you wrote "I don't think that Rome would stand heavy armored horsement and the weapon advancements of the Franks." I was thinking that the counter-advancements that Rome would have made against them should be taken into account, especially since Rome made sure its generals took every advantage they could get. Hence my question. But the question asks from point of view of "a Roman army is immediately time-travelled and dropped in front of heavy armored horsemen and the weapon advancements of the Franks" such that the Roman army has no time to adjust, so my comment is not valid.